# Redirect Http to Https?

Tags: spring-boot, http, tomcat, redirect

In my jar version SNAPSHOT 1.3, i can go to my application vsprava.com:433 from local computer and from another computer.

But than i add tomcat settings in newest version, that set up redirect without this port :433, and everything work good from local computer, i can visit my site use vsprava.com, but when i run from another computer vsprava.com, **This site can’t be reached vsprava.com took too long to respond.**

```
@Configuration
public class TomcatConfigure {
    
    
    @Bean
    public ServletWebServerFactory servletContainer() {
        TomcatServletWebServerFactory tomcat = new TomcatServletWebServerFactory() {@Override
            protected void postProcessContext(Context context) {
                SecurityConstraint securityConstraint = new SecurityConstraint();
                securityConstraint.setUserConstraint("CONFIDENTIAL");
                SecurityCollection collection = new SecurityCollection();
                collection.addPattern("/*");
                securityConstraint.addCollection(collection);
                context.addConstraint(securityConstraint);
            }
        };
        tomcat.addAdditionalTomcatConnectors(redirectConnector());
        return tomcat;
    }

    private Connector redirectConnector() {
        Connector connector = new Connector("org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11NioProtocol");
        connector.setScheme("http");
        connector.setPort(80);
        connector.setSecure(false);
        connector.setRedirectPort(443);
        return connector;
    }
```

My properties

```
server.port=443
server.address=0.0.0.0
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/law?useSSl=false
spring.datasource.username = root
spring.datasource.password = 123456789Vv
spring.datasource.driver-class-name=com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver
spring.main.allow-circular-references=true

## SSL 
server.ssl.key-store=classpath:ssl/vsprava.p12
server.ssl.key-store-password=123456789Vv
server.ssl.key-store-type=PKCS12
server.ssl.enabled=true
##server.ssl.enabled-protocols=TLSv1,TLSv1.1,TLSv1.2,SSLv3,SSLv2,TLS
server.ssl.key-alias=1
```

P.S. without whis tomcat setting i can get access from another computer, vsprava.com:433

Comment: Also i check in Port Checker, my port 80 open, but port 443 is closed, why ?
In version 1.3. port 443 is open